# AVAudioPlayer NOT playing through speaker after recording with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I'm working on an app that does audio recording and playback of recorded audio. I'm using `AVAudioSession` to change the category to `playAndRecord` as well as passing it to `defaultToSpeaker`.

**My problem is**, if I launch the app, play an earlier recording, it plays through the bottom (louder) speaker as I want it to and expected BUT if I launch the app and start recording a new memo then play it back, no matter what I do, it will always use the quieter (phone call) speaker that's next to front face camera. I need it to play from the louder speaker (actually all speakers if possible).

NOTE: I'm running iOS 14.2.1, my phone is set to silent mode (usually) though I tried other settings as well. I'm testing on an iPhone 12. Ideally, I'm not really looking for a 3rd party SDK or library solution as I want the playback to be simple and done natively.

This is how I set the audioSession in my viewModel (that's initialized from a viewController):

```
private func setupAudioSession() {
    do {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth])
        try session.setActive(true)
        session.requestRecordPermission({ [weak self] allowed in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if allowed == false {
                self.settingsAlert?()
            }
        })
    } catch {
        debugPrint("error setting up AVAudioSession")
    }
}
```

This is how I do recording:

```
func startRecording() {
    guard let audioFileDir = getAudioFilePath(songId: songModel!.id) else { return }
    let audioURLString = audioFileDir.absoluteString + ".m4a"
    guard let audioURL = URL(string: audioURLString) else { return }
    let recordingSettings: [String: Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44_100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: isStereoSupported ? 2 : 1,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16
    ]
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: recordingSettings)
        audioUrl = audioURL
        audioRecorder?.delegate = self
        audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder?.record()
    } catch {
        audioRecorder = nil
        debugPrint("Problem recording audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I even included some code from WWDC 2020 for stereo recording and that's what isStereoSupported does.

And this is how I do playback

```
do {
    if let data = songDoc?.data?.audioData {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
    } else if let url = audioUrl {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }
    audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    audioPlayer?.play()
    isPlaying = true
} catch {
    audioPlayer = nil
    debugPrint("playback error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Of course I have tried adding things like:

```
try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
```

as well as setting the AVAudioSession each time I play or record. I've tried bunch of other similar things to fix this issue but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get AVAudioPlayer output to the speaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022992/how-to-get-avaudioplayer-output-to-the-speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set audio session mode to AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording
and set session category options to AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker

[session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording error:&e]

Comment: YES! That was it! Thank you so much. I haven't seen this AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording anywhere in my searches on StackOverflow or online.